# Accordion creation in CRM

Tags: javascript, jquery, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am very much new to CRM, I got a requirement, asking me to create a simple accordion with name and status - as panel heading. And after expanding the panel, I should give all the details about the user details in the entity. All the details will be fetched dynamically from the back end. Can some one help me in writing this. I don't know how to start. everything will be dynamic, depends on the field in the DB. Hope I explained clearly

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should design a accordion or dropdown-toggle etc with html, css and JavaScript . Second you should call Ajax to fetch data from back-end then back-end gonna return a JSON. After that you should assign values to their own places. The code below is a sample for calling an Ajax with JQuery:

```
var parameters = {id:10};
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: parameters,
  datatype: "json",
  url: '@Url.Action("ProductList", "Product")',
  success: function(result){
   $("#username").attr('value', result.Username);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, sorry for the late response. I am working on it. will try this and will let you know if I face any issue.